# Highcharts - Add a tooltip suffix value dynamically for each series

Tags: angular, highcharts, tooltip

I am working on highcharts, trying to update tooltip valueSuffix dynamically for each series but could not get it working. Any help much appreciated.

here is some sample code, data array is containing currency symbols that needs to be displayed dynamically for each series.

```
this.chartConfig.ref$.subscribe(result => {
      result.series[0].points.forEach((pnt, i) => {
          if(pnt.series.tooltipOptions) {
            pnt.series.tooltipOptions.valueSuffix = data[i].currencySymbol;
          }
      });
    });
```

tried with the update method but it is just showing the first symbol on each series

```
      this.chartConfig.ref.series.forEach((series, index) => {
          series.update({tooltip: {valueSuffix: data[index].currencySymbol}}, false);        
      });
      this.chartConfig.ref.redraw(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's more simplest way to change suffix dynamically, adding tooltip property to each series.
If this is not enough, prepare a simplified demo version with your code.

```
series: [
  {
    type: "line",
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    tooltip: {
      valueDecimals: 1,
      valuePrefix: '$',
      valueSuffix: ' USD'
    },
  },
  {
    type: "column",
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reverse(),
    tooltip: {
      valueDecimals: 2,
      valuePrefix: '€',
      valueSuffix: ' EUR'
    },
  }
],
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-oggjca?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

API References:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.tooltip